# With Safari, can I allow pop-ups for specific sites?

Tags: safari

I have chosen "Block popup windows" in Safari's security tab, yet there are a couple of sites for work that still use popups for login etc. Is there a way to add exceptions (in advanced settings or directly in the plist file perhaps?) Or maybe via a Safari extension?

Comment: use Adblocker, allow pop-ups in safari, then add a rule to addblocker

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, with Safari Version 12 or higher, you can allow popups for a specific website. Here are step-by-step instructions:

1. Right click on the URL (when you're NOT in a text entry mode)

   [image: Menu when you click on the URL]
2. Select "Settings for This Website..."
3. Select "Allow" under "Pop-up Windows"

   [image: Website settings]

Comment: Does not work for me: Safari 11.1.2 in macOS 10.11.6.

Comment: Can you not get the initial menu to come up? If not, one thing to check is that you’re not in text entry mode in the URL field — try clicking on the page first, and then right clicking on the URL.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail. There is no "Pop-up Windows" entry in Safari 11.1.2 in macOS 10.11.6.

Comment: Ah, thanks for letting me know. I’ll edit my answer.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any exception list for popups in Safari.  It's an "all-or-nothing" approach for now.

I recommend telling Apple your thoughts on the Safari feedback page: http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html

**EDIT 12/20**: This answer is correct as of the time it was written.  Since then, Apple has added the ability to control popups per site.  [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/349407/88313) by @matt-chandler is the correct one for newer versions of Safari.  I'm leaving this answer here in case it helps people on older versions of Safari.